# How to check if columns in CSV file are null or not thorough shell scripting

Tags: csv, unix

I have a CSV file like this

```
dsdgh||@jhsjdh||jdhjdhfu|123|
#45ghf|123|laiej||||
|hyrhyf|||fhyr|@#$%|
```

how to fine whether a column is empty or not if any of the column is empty then print the resilt in result.txt file

I need a shell script to solve above problem

Above CSV is pipe delimited

Can any one help ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file can't contain `null` values. You can at most interpret special values (e. g. empty strings) as null value. You can test for empty strings with `test`(1) or rather `[`(1) as follows

```
if [ -z "$column" ]
then
    # do magic
fi
```

Comment: HI , Thanks for help, Can you please elaborate it as i am new and didnt get your  script

Comment: This is just an example. I have no complete script.